# UITableViewController not responding to keyboard

Tags: uitableview, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

Im trying to let a tableview adjust to the showing of the keyboard in Swift.
According to the docs, the tableview should auto adjust if it is a subclass of UITableViewController.
Read a lot of answers here already and just to make sure I got it all covered:

- It is a subclass of UITableViewController

  `class SettingsController: UITableViewController`
- ViewWillAppear is not overridden, so I don't need to call `super.viewWillAppear(true)`

I just have a textfield in a static tableview cell, but when the keyboard comes up, the tableview doesn't scroll.

Other then that, I tried to implement the notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: self)
```

with the function

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("Keyboard shown")
}
```

But the function never gets called.

Who can help me out here? Why is the tableview not scrolling and why is the notification not fired?

Regards,

Ron

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe you have to add a colon after the selector to show that it takes arguments, so `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: self)`

Comment: Hi Jack, already tried that, and now again but doesn't help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi Ron, did you find the reason why UITableViewController isn't scrolling automatically ? I have same problem

Comment: Hi @Borbea, I have never actually found what is causing the problem. I fixed it by doing it manually with the keyboard notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are passing self into the function as the object. Self is of type SettingsController and so when it looks for a method called "keyboardWasShown:" with a SettingsController parameter, it doesn't find one. This can be fixed in two ways, either change the first line to pass in a nil value:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

or alternatively change the method to accept a SettingsController

```
func keyboardWasShown(settingsController: SettingsController) {
    println("Keyboard shown")
}
```

Hopefully that will fix any problems you have.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I thought it crashes at first. But I think it was a combination of adding the ':' to the selector and settings the object to nil. But I still can't understand why the tableviewcontroller won't do it automatic. Apple's docs says it should.